# How to Validate Email Address and Give Phone No Dropdown in MVC4 Razor View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to Validate EmailID in my textbox in MVC as well as I want to create Phone No. same as Gmail signup process where 2 dropdowns are there one for Country and other for Phone NO.Can some one please help me creating this I will be very thankful I have to Use MVC4 Razor View

Thanks for Your Quick Response EmailValidation I have done but I am facing issues while implementing phone No .I am attaching the image which I want to implement please help me to implement and sorry for not attaching the code I have almost done a registration form only this on is pending

Comment: What have you done so far? We are not here to do your work for you, but rather assist you with you current problem.

Comment: what u meant by "I want to create Phone No. same as Gmail signup process" ?

Comment: I want to implement Phone No where we have one drowdown inside that country codes with image is there and other one is simple mob no.If you will see to create gmail account you will come to know what I want to implement actually I don't have reputation otherwise I would have showed screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add data annotations on your Model:

**Sample Model Class**

```
public class UserInformation
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Url]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [CreditCard]
    public string CreditCard { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,jpeg")]
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

There is also another way:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { type = "email" })
```